# Непонятное поведение all

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть база с 1000 записей. При выполнении

```
@movies = Movies.all
```

На выходе имею ActiveRecord::Relation, почему то начиная не с начала, а с 33 объекта. При переборе each с него и начинается.

```
@movies = Movies.first(1000)
```

Возвращает все, включая первые 32 элемента, но это массив, @movies.first тоже даст доступ к первому элементу.
Как мне получить все записи и с чем вообще связано странное поведение all? Почему именно с 33 объекта?

Comment: А если `Movies.order(id: :asc).all`? И чисто из любопытства, какая у вас СУБД?

Comment: А так - все нормально. База - PG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Документация PostgreSQL](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/queries-order.html) (или [в оригинале](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-order.html)) говорит прямо (жирный шрифт от меня):

> Если **сортировка не задана**, строки возвращаются в **неопределённом порядке**. Фактический порядок строк в этом случае будет зависеть от плана соединения и сканирования, а также от порядка данных на диске, поэтому полагаться на него нельзя. Определённый порядок выводимых строк гарантируется, только если этап сортировки задан явно.

Так что где вас интересует порядок, [добавляйте его явно с помощью метода `.order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order):

```
Movies.order(:id).all
```

Такое происходит не только в постгресе. Привыкайте — что не указано в запросе явно, обычно не гарантируется, если только документация явно не утверждает обратного. Это позволяет базе не заниматься лишней работой (а сортировка, бывает, требует усилий), когда она не требуется — как следствие, работать быстрее в целом.

---

Почему с `first` такого не происходит, тоже сказано [в документации, но к `first` из Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first):

> If no order is defined it will order by primary key.

> Если порядок не указан, будет использован порядок по первичному ключу

---

Скорее всего, неначальные строчки пролезли в начало в результате запуска процедуры обслуживания постгреса, [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-vacuum.html), которая отмечает дисковое место от удалённых и старых версий изменённых строчек как доступное для повторного использования (MVCC ведь, изменение строки на самом деле записывает новую версию и отмечает старую мёртвой).

В дальнейшем, при добавлении новых строк и изменении старых (опять же, MVCC) новые данные будут попадать на это освобождённое место. А поскольку самый простой для постгреса скан это последовательный по диску, без явной сортировки строчки могут здорово перемешиваться по мере эксплуатации БД.